# Pagination issue in nop commerce

Tags: nopcommerce

I am getting a pagination issue in nop commerce 2.3 don't know how to resolve it:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Comment: Can you please show us some code? Merely showing the error is often not enough. :)

Comment: Anyway, it seems like it is caused by error in your calculation. You might have tried to convert an integer that's too large to be represented by an integer. How large is your data size? :)

Comment: the calculation is done by default in the nopcommerce solution and I have not altered it I dont even know where is it done.
Please help I am in a great problem

Comment: Please let me know what page are you accessing, with what URL and query strings (if any). :)

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is a sql error. 
This is caused by a calculated column value that exceeds the column's specified size.

Suppose you have three columns c1, c2, and c3 are defined as a data type of INTEGER. Further, assume that c3 is computed using the formula ([c1] * [c2]). If large values (such as 9999) are entered into c1 and c2, then the computation of c3 might exceed the allowable INTEGER limit.

That means you might have to change the data type of a particular column. You can use "bigint" instead of 'int'

Comment: Nice clarification.